# Post in a facebook's friend wall is not generating the notification

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm using the FB.api to post to a friend's wall... here is the code:

```
    function postToWallFB(friendId, postMsg, name, link, description, picture){
    var opts = {
        message : postMsg,
        name : name,
        link : link,
        description : description,
        picture : picture
    };

    FB.api('/'+friendId+'/feed', 'post', opts, function(response)
    {


            if (!response || response.error)
            {
                alert('Error');                 
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Ok');

            }

    }); 
}
```

the function is working great... the image and everything is showing correctly in my friend's wall... but when i enter with the account that received the post, it doesnt show any notification in the top left buttons of my interface.

does anyone have any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Enter with which account, are you using Test Users to check?